# Track new events someone else created in a shared Google calendar via email or notification

Tags: google-calendar

I use several shared calendars as part of my business. Often with several people editing and adding events to the calendar, sometimes weeks or months in the future, it's difficult to know and keep track of what people are adding into the calendar.

Is there a way to track and get updates on all new events that are added by someone other than yourself in a shared calendar?

Answer (score 8):

You can enable the "changed events" notifications to receive notifications of events that change using the settings menu.

- Go to the settings menu (the gear), select the Calendars tab, and go through to edit the notifications of the specific calendar for which you want to receive these notifications.
- Enable notifications for "changed events" from the menu of different triggers - http://screencast.com/t/Z4n5qUezDv

This also applies to the "new events" trigger, but that relies on your email being invited to the event.

Comment: Thanks mfg. That doesn't completed answer the question but it is a good solution if someone creates then edits the new event.

Comment: As of April 2018, it is possible to get an email notification, but it seems there is no way of getting a push notification when a new event is created.

Comment: If you share the calendar with someone, they will not receive email updates for new events unless you set their access permissions to 'make changes and manage sharing'. I just confirmed this, btw.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a simple, free Android app for this purpose, you can find it here:

[Calendar Watcher on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calengoo.android.calendarchanges)

You can select which calendars should be watched and it will display status bar notifications for each change in these watched calendars (but also for your own changes):

[image: Example notification]

Comment: Man, thank you for this! This is awesome and exactly what I needed! ^_^ Just makes me sad this does not have more upvotes... #kudos!

Comment: Thank you very much, I am glad that you like it! :-)

Comment: This app is excellent with 1 drawback : we receive notifications when we create an event. The idea is to receive notifications only when others create events (because I know what I create... usualy... lol )

Comment: @sangorys I am glad that you like the app! Yes, unfortunately I didn't find a way to determine if a change was made by the current user or by someone else. So the app can only show all changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the calendar with this person and set their access permissions to 'make changes and manage sharing'. Details on how to do these things is at https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en. It's unfortunate that you need to give them this level of access in order to get the notifications to work the way that you want.